# How to list running silverlight applications

Tags: .net, silverlight, profiling, profiler

Is there a way to find out silverlight applications that are running on all internet browsers (including IE). In fact I'm a newbie at profiling and I'd like to make a custom .NET Applications Profiler.
Are there by the way APIs to communicate with Silverlight applications?
Which version of silverlight is the easiest to profile (according to the APIs provided)?
 Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of months ago I did a small project that enumerates all .NET and SL processes. You can find it here http://iobservable.net/blog/?p=107

Comment: "Insanity is doing the same thing over and over again and expecting a different result."